# How do I cancel drag between different lists when using angular-ui's sortable module

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui

I am using angular-ui's sortable-ui module and am trying to raise a cancel so that the dragged items returns to it original location in the source list.  Unfortunately I cannot get this working.  Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ej99f/1/

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.sortable']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
$scope.list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

$scope.list2 = ["7", "8", "9"];

$scope.sortableOptions = {
    update: function(e, ui) {
        if (Number(ui.item.text()) === 6) {
            ui.item.parent().sortable('cancel');
        }
    },
    receive: function(e, ui) {            
        ui.sender.sortable('cancel');
        ui.item.parent().sortable('cancel'); 
    },
    connectWith: ".group",
    axis: 'y'
};
```

});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Probably you should use `revert` to return the element.

Comment: According to the documentation, revert is a property that controls the animation.  Is this not correct?

Answer (score 2):

well, when it comes to angular, all roads lead to the data "the single source of truth". So update your model back to it's original state, before the move, and you're all set :)

example below has two lists, the first one being restricted for 
its sorting (the update method) 
and for sending an item (receive method on list 2)

the second list you can sort, and send items to list 1
(using foundation4 for css)

```
<div ng-app="test">        
    <div ng-controller="sortableTest">
    <div class="small-4 columns panel">
        <ul data-drop="true"
            ui-sortable="sortable.options.list1" ng-model="sortable.model.list1">
            <li ng-repeat="fruit in sortable.model.list1"
                data-id="{{ fruit.id }}">{{ fruit.label }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="small-4 columns panel">
        <ul data-drop="true"
            ui-sortable="sortable.options.list2" ng-model="sortable.model.list2">
            <li ng-repeat="element in sortable.model.list2"
                data-id="{{ element.id }}">{{ element.label }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
    <br />
    <span ng-repeat="fruit in sortable.model.list1">{{ fruit.label }} </span><br />
    <span ng-repeat="element in sortable.model.list2">{{ element.label }} </span><br />
    <span ng-repeat="fruit in sortable.oldData.list1">{{ fruit.label }} </span><br />
    <span ng-repeat="element in sortable.oldData.list2">{{ element.label }} </span><br />
</div>
</div>

js:

var test = angular.module('test', ['ui.sortable']);

test.controller('sortableTest', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.sortable = {
        model: {
            list1: [{id: 1, label: 'apple'},{id: 2, label: 'orange'},{id: 3, label: 'pear'},{id: 4, label: 'banana'}],
            list2: [{id: 5, label: 'earth'},{id: 6, label: 'wind'},{id: 7, label: 'fire'},{id: 8, label: 'water'}]
        },
        oldData: {
            list1: [],
            list2: []
        },
        options: {
            list1: {
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    console.debug('up-list1');
                    $scope.sortable.oldData.list1 = $scope.sortable.model.list1.slice(0);
                    $scope.sortable.oldData.list2 = $scope.sortable.model.list2.slice(0);
                    // DO NOT USE THIS! it messes up the data. 
                    // ui.item.parent().sortable('cancel');  // <--- BUGGY!
                    // uncomment and check the span repeats..

                    $timeout(function(){
                        $scope.sortable.model.list1 = $scope.sortable.oldData.list1;
                        $scope.sortable.model.list2 = $scope.sortable.oldData.list2;
                    });
                },
                connectWith: 'ul'
            },
            list2: {
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    console.debug('up-list2');

                },
                connectWith: 'ul',
                receive: function(event, ui) {
                    console.debug('re-list2');

                    $timeout(function(){
                        $scope.sortable.model.list1 = $scope.sortable.oldData.list1;
                        $scope.sortable.model.list2 = $scope.sortable.oldData.list2;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

you can of course use a service or something to store the old value. One can use ui.sender to differentiate the senders, if you have more that two..